# I'm trying to create a table on my database using PHP so far i have managed to create a database using PHP but but fail to create table/tables

Tags: php, html

```
<?PHP

    try{
        $handler = new PDO($servername, $username, $password);
        $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE user_details ( 
            id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            fullname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            password VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL,
            gender ENUM('male','female','other','')  NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (id)) 
            ENGINE = InnoDB
            )";
        echo "Sucessfullll";
        $handler->exc($sql);
    } catch (PDOException $msg){
        echo $msg->getMessage();
        die();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: no error messages

Comment: you have to mention the database name, in which table has to be created

Comment: I have changed exc to exec still not creating it

Comment: Sorry for the content change I'm still getting used to this

Comment: Typo `)";` the ENGINE does not need a `)` after it especially an unmatched one.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra unmatched parentheses `)`

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE user_details ( 
           id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
           email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
           fullname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
           username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
           password VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL,
           gender ENUM('male','female','other','')  NOT NULL ,
           PRIMARY KEY (id)
      ) ENGINE = InnoDB )";
```

Should be

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE user_details ( 
           id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
           email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
           fullname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
           username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
           password VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL,
           gender ENUM('male','female','other','')  NOT NULL ,
           PRIMARY KEY (id)
      ) ENGINE = InnoDB";
```

You also might need the length for the INT,  I forget.

**INDEXES**

I always do my id's like this `id INT(10) UNSINGED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT` because well no one like having a negative ID.  And I would make `UNIQUE(username)` And `UNIQUE(email)` and maybe an `INDEX(fullname)`.

Indexes depend on what you plan on searching, the more indexes you have the long it takes to insert and update records.  But for your average website it's pretty unnoticeable.

If you plan on inserting 10's of thousands of rows at a time, you would want to be more careful with indexes, because for each index it takes a bit extra time to compile them when modifying the data.

**NAMING CONVENTIONS**

Your field names look good, no plurals no casing.  The only thing I would change here is name the table just `users`, I usually pluralize tables, and use `_` as a way to mark a junction table, or a table that ties 2 tables together with a Many To Many relationship.  So for example I would have `users` and `addresses` and then a table that joined them `users_addresses`.

If it's a table with a One to many, I will do a non-plural for the one and a plural for the many.  So if each user could have many uploads.  One to Many,   I would name it like `user_uploads`.  That way I can see what kind of relationship it is without opening up PHPmyAdmin or trying to remember how I set it up.

I just wanted to mention that, because the name you have going by my naming conventions, it would be a table with details in it with a user_id foreign key.

I should say everyone does naming conventions a bit differently the main thing is to name things for a reason, and be consistent.

**last thing**

This is just my Opinion, but I find it better to connect this way:

```
$options = [
     PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
     PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
];

$handler = new PDO($servername, $username, $password, $options);
```

By sending it as options, it will throw an exception when you fail to connect.  Otherwise you haven't set the mode until after the initial connection.  And probably about 90% of the time I use associative arrays for my return, so you can set that too.

cheers!

Comment: Sure, I use PDO quite a lot.....  I think I wrote 5 queries just yesterday.  And wrote about 1500 lines of code... and that was just for my day job.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what value you have stored in `$servername` variable. If you are storing just the IP address or hostname, then it's wrong.

The first argument to the PDO constructor is a Data Source Name (`dsn`). An example of a MySQL DSN is:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$handler = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

Comment: mine is $servername = 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test'; i think its the same.